# jQuery if does not have class do not trigger function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am gonna go straight to the point. Basically, I've got following HTML structure:

```
<div id="global-container">
    <div class="content-pusher">
        <a class="mobile-menu-btn" href="#">Mobile menu btn</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And following JavaScript/jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    // Side panel.
    $('.content-pusher').click(function(e) {
        $this = $(this);
        if ($this.parents('#global-container').hasClass('side-panel-open'))
        {
            $this.parents('#global-container').removeClass('side-panel-open');
        }
    });

    $('.mobile-menu-btn').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        $('#global-container').addClass('side-panel-open');
    });
});
```

The thing is that I want to add a class `side-panel-open` to `#global-container` when you click a `Mobile menu btn` and remove it when you click on `content-pusher` div.

**Problem:**
When I click on `Mobile  menu btn` it adds `side-panel-open` class to `#global-container` div and also removes it straight away because `Mobile menu btn` is inside `content-pusher`. (I cannot put it outside that div).

At first I thought as `$('.content-pusher').click...` triggers earlier than `$('.mobule-menu-btn').click...` it should work, but it doesn't as it returns TRUE when I check if there is a class `side-panel-open` on div `#global-container` even if this class gets added after that function.

**JSFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/xFdKx/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest handling clicks on the `#global-container`, and checking where they originated:

```
$('#global-container').on('click', 'div.content-pusher, a.mobile-menu-btn', function(e){
    $('#global-container').toggleClass('side-panel-open', $(e.target).is('a.mobile-menu-btn'));
});
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PP2QH/3/).

References:

- [`event.target` (jQuery)](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/).
- [`event.target` (DOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.target)
- [`is()`](http://api.jquery.com/is/).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
- [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/).

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the propagation of the click event from the `mobile-menu-btn` element

```
$(function () {
    // Side panel.
    $('.content-pusher').click(function (e) {
        //since you have the id of the element there is no need to use the parents method here
        $('#global-container').removeClass('side-panel-open');
        //$(this).parents('#global-container').removeClass('side-panel-open');
    });

    $('.mobile-menu-btn').click(function (e) {
        $('#global-container').addClass('side-panel-open');
        return false;
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PP2QH/)

Comment: Just a point, but I think you forgot to add jQuery to your demo (unless I'm missing something very clever, which is always possible...) :)

Comment: It's in external resources. :P